# JQuery Script to change href not working

Tags: jquery, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I want to change the CSS file with radio options but I just can't make the script work. I inserted some code to test it but it won't work either. I am using the Bootstrap framework and it works fine, the CSS files work too.

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link id="estilos" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./BootstrapColorSchemes/hefestus.css" >
    <title>Spider Magic</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="myForm">
        <div class="radio-inline">
            <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"
              value="./BootstrapColorSchemes/adventuetime1.css">AT1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-inline">
            <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"
              value="./BootstrapColorSchemes/adventuretime2.css">AT2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-inline">
            <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"
              value="./BootstrapColorSchemes/adventuretime3.css">AT3</label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div>This border should be red</div>
    <script src="./js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"/>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('i am ready');
        $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
        $('#myForm input').on('change',function(){
            var selected=$('input[name="optradio"]:checked','#myForm').val();
            $('#estilos').attr('href',selected);
            alert(selected)
        });
    });</script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script tag can not be self closed with the solidus needs a close tag:

```
<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And to change the css this should work:

```
$('.radio-inline').click(function() {
  $('#estilos').attr('href', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: You are not checking if it is 'checked'

Comment: I would write the event handler as: `$('#myForm').on('change', 'input[type=radio][name="optradio"]',function () {` to take advantage of the radio type and form scope but the real issue was as you noted the script tag closure.